# How to get img id

Tags: javascript, image

i have this simple code. But it doesn't work. How create a working code? Please help

```
<form action="">
<img id="3323" src="http://site-sample.com/pic.jpg"></img>
<input type="button" value="GET ID" onClick="GetID(this.form)">
</form>

<scirpt>
function GetID(f){
img_id = f.img.attr('id');
alert(img_id);
};
</script>
```

Comment: Two things: Your opening `<script>`-tag has a typo in it, and usually you need to set a `type`-attribute on it.  Try `<script type="text/javascript">` for the opening tag. Better would probably be `<script type="application/javascript">`, but I'm not sure how well that is supported.

Comment: @Jost - you do not need a `type` attribute on `<script>` tags if the type is Javascript.  This has been codified as a standard in HTML5, and works in all browsers.

Comment: `this.form` is likely not what you expect it to be.  It's probably `undefined`.

Answer (score 1):

Use [getElementsByTagName()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName) to get elements with the given tag name, then use [Element.getAttribute()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute) returns the value of a specified attribute on the element.

```
f.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].getAttribute('id')`
```

```js
  function GetID(f) {
    img_id = f.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].getAttribute('id');
    alert(img_id);
  };
```

```html
<form action="">
  <img id="3323" src="http://sait.ru/pic.jpg"></img>
  <input type="button" value="GET ID" onClick="GetID(this.form)" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<form action="">
  <img id="3323" src="http://site-sample.com/pic.jpg" />
  <input type="button" value="GET ID" />
</form>

<script>

  function GetID(f) {
    img_id = f.querySelector('img').getAttribute('id');
    alert(img_id);
  } 
  var button =document.querySelector("form input[type=button]");

  button.addEventListener("click",function(){
     GetID(this.form)
  },false);

</script>
```